# ¿ yield( ) en manejador de interrupciones?

Tags: c

Tengo una `struct` que tengo que copiar; eso no presenta ningún problema, salvo que **durante** la copia se active una interrupción, y la función manejadora **modifique** los datos de esa `struct`.

En principio, no habría problema. Protegemos los datos mediante llamadas a

```
atomic_flag_test_and_set( );
```

Si estuviéramos en un entorno *multithread*, podriamos hacer un `thrd_yield( );`, cediendo la CPU a otro proceso mientras que no podamos acceder a los datos protegidos.

Pero, ¿ y si estamos en un manejador de interrupciones ?. Aquí no podemos hacer un `thrd_yield( );`

La pregunta, pués, es la siguiente:

> ¿ Como esperar, dentro de una función manejadora de interrupciones, a
>   que un recurso quede libre, sin volver a *relanzar* la interrupción ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Como esperar, dentro de una función manejadora de interrupciones, a que un recurso quede libre, sin volver a relanzar la interrupción ?

No necesitas esperar nada, si el recurso esta ocupado, encola un mensaje (en una cola creada para tal fin) y en la próxima pasada (ya sea de la interrupción o del proceso) aplicas los cambios "encolados" al `struct` antes de realizar la operación de turno.

Esta técnica se usa mucho en telecomunicaciones y se le llama *cola postpone*. Donde se pospone la ejecución de ciertas tareas hasta que estén dadas las condiciones. Básicamente sirve para sincronizar estados ortogonales. Es decir para manejar todas las transiciones que solo son posibles desde un estado particular.

Comment: Buena idea; no conocía el nombre *tecnico*. En este caso concreto, para actualizar datos estadísticos, solo puede existir un *evento* en esa cola, por lo que sería muy fácil de implementar. Un positivo, de momento. Si no hay mejores respuestas en un plazo *razonable*, te la acepto.